# Does Picasso's resizeDimen() method take dp or pixels?

Tags: android, picasso

I am quite confused about resizing with Picasso. If I understand it correctly, we have to pass pixels to the `resize` method, so we manually have to convert them from dp to support different screen densities.
But what does the `resizeDimen`method do? Does it take dimension in dp so we don't have to convert them manually anymore?
How is that related to the `fit` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `resizeDimen` use dimen resource (not dp nether px). Dimen resources looks like `<dimen name="logo_width">96dp</dimen>` and they are used like this : `R.dimen.logo_width`.
- `resize` method use **pixel**
- `fit` method will resize your source according to the target size (usually an ImageView)

Note : The conversion from any dimension units to pixels is made by an Android context (the context in `Picasso.with(context)`). Take a look at this [method](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/5ddd855c1e98379a1812c0ccccbdc200a30312cc/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java#L226) from Picasso source code and this [method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/util/TypedValue.java#384) from Android source code to understand how conversion works.

Comment: That's what confuses me. Why does the `resize` method not provide the option to resize to dp instead of px, but the `resizeDimen` method takes a resource ID which points to dp?

Comment: The standard unit for Picasso is the pixel (as you can see in the resize method). But for the resizeDimen method this not Picasso which convert the value from [every dimension unit] to px, this is the Android System.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, this way I can avoid converting dp to pixels manually and instead pass a dp res id?

Comment: Yes, Picasso use a context to convert your value (the context in Picasso.with(context)). You can take a look at this method in Picasso source code : https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/5ddd855c1e98379a1812c0ccccbdc200a30312cc/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java#L226

Comment: Thank you. You both were really really helpful.

Comment: You can also mark your favorite answer to highlight the topic for people who have the same question.

Comment: Ok. What do you think about editing that internal dp-conversion part into the answer? That's what helped me most.

Answer (score 3):

No. `resizeDimen` also resizes in pixels except you don't have to give the exact integer value but instead you can pass the resource ID.

So `resize(96,96)` is the same as `reSizeDimen(R.dimen.header_logo_w, R.dimen.header_logo_h)` where

```
 res/values/dimens.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="header_logo_h">96px</dimen>
<dimen name="header_logo_w">96px</dimen>
</resources>
```

Let me know if you need further explaination

Comment: Ok, thank you. So if I don't use `fit()` then I always have to take care of converting dp to px myself, right?

Comment: And what happens if i pass a resource ID that is defined in dp?

Comment: @FlorianWalther - If you study the source code of Picasso - you will see that it will always convert the integer value in your resource file to its equivalent pixels using resources.getDimensionPixelSize -> 
 https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/5ddd855c1e98379a1812c0ccccbdc200a30312cc/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java

Comment: Thank you! Will this take the different screen densities into account? So, can I use `resizeDimen` to avoid converting dp to pixels manually, or do I understand that wrong?